# Type or namespace name Forms does not exist in the namespace Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I downloaded VS2019 and proceeded to create a Solution and Project to learn Xamarin.  I have tried using different templates (Mobile apps or just iOS) with the same result.  Without changing anything in the resultant forms etc., if I build the solution I get the error that Forms does not exist in Xamarin.  I have tried to download Xamarin.Forms, but it says it is already installed.  I have searched and Googled and while there are similar questions of "name XXX does not exist in namespace YYY", none of those solutions apply in my case.  I have tried to re-install VS, done a "repair" to VS.  Many sites suggest closing and re-opening the solution (or cleaning), or restoring Nuget - none of that helps.  The iOS project contains a reference to Xamarin.ios and I can see Xamarin.Forms under that so it does exist, but the project can't seem to find it.  I know people like to see code here, but I haven't done any coding yet.

[Solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu5kD.png)

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8e8w.png)

[AppDelegate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0hnO.png)

Comment: first, you cannot build an iOS project on Windows unless you have a Mac build server setup.  Do you?

Comment: Also make sure you update all the packages to latest when you first create a new solution.

Comment: Sorry - I'm new to this, but if by "Mac build server setup" you mean have it connected to a Mac computer, yes I do.  It went through a whole series of checks on the Mac and said connection succeeded.  Or am I missing something and you are referring to something else?

Comment: I think the packages are all updated, but I'll do a double check on that.

Comment: @dfrostad Could you share a screenshot or video of error , I will check it .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I've added images to the Solution structure, the errors and the AppDelegate where the errors occur.

Comment: @FreakyAli  When I go to Restore Nuget Packages I get this error:  Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: The local source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Thinktecture' doesn't exist.

Comment: @dfrostad update them to latest man!

Comment: @FreakyAli Easier said than done.  What baffles me is why this occurs right "out of the box", without changing anything.  Shouldn't the latest version of VS be THE LATEST?  I had tried updating all, but it failed without telling me why.  Anyway, the solution was to manually add a folder called Thinktecture in Microsoft SDKs, then do the update.  It then gives me a host of warnings about "Can't resolve the conflict between....", but it chooses the latest version and the Build works.  Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: @dfrostad Glad to hear that ！Later remember to mark answer when you can  :)

Comment: @dfrostad When you create a template and add nugets to it that template will download those nugets only now sometimes issues occur when one nuget starts to conflict with the other, like your scenario that is the reason the microsoft docs will say that you make sure that you update all nugets to the latest when you create a new project!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to manually add a folder called Thinktecture in C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs, then do an update of Xamarin.ios. It then gives a host of warnings about "Can't resolve the conflict between....", but it chooses the latest version and the Build works.